# Is there a way to filter on the number of votes?

Tags: support, filtering

I would like to make a filter that only shows questions or questions with an answer with X or higher votes, but sorted by newest. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put

```
 votes:10
```

in the search box to get only posts with at least a score of 10. You can sort that result by newest when you switch to the *Newest* tab.

[image: search]

You can get search tips when you click on *Advanced search Tips* on the left.

Comment: Ok great! Is there a way to look for questions _or_ answers with 10 or higher though?

Comment: It searches for both by default: You can limit it to either one with `is:question` or `is:answer`. See the *Advanced search Tips* on the right of my screenshot.